# GDI+ flickering

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, flicker, double-buffering

So I'm trying to make a cheap copy of Gyazo (the screenshotting tool)

The problem is that the cursor coordinates are flickering, how can I prevent that? I have already tried `WM_ERASEBKGND` but it doesn't help anything.

Also is there anything else wrong with my code? Any bad practices / techniques?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Gdiplus.lib")

// Store the "screenshot" when first launching the program
HBITMAP hbm;

// This draws the cursor coordinates close to the cursor
void DrawCursorCoords(Gdiplus::Graphics &graphics, Gdiplus::Bitmap &bitmap, Gdiplus::Color c)
{
    POINT cursorPos;
    GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);

    std::wstring x = std::to_wstring(cursorPos.x);
    std::wstring y = std::to_wstring(cursorPos.y);

    graphics.DrawString(x.c_str(), x.length(), &Gdiplus::Font(L"Consolas", 16), Gdiplus::PointF(cursorPos.x, cursorPos.y), &Gdiplus::SolidBrush(c));
    graphics.DrawString(y.c_str(), y.length(), &Gdiplus::Font(L"Consolas", 16), Gdiplus::PointF(cursorPos.x, cursorPos.y + 16), &Gdiplus::SolidBrush(c));
}

// Paint our stuff
void Paint(HDC &hdc)
{
    Gdiplus::Graphics * gfx = new Gdiplus::Graphics(hdc);
    Gdiplus::Bitmap * bmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(hbm, (HPALETTE)0);

    gfx->DrawImage(bmap, 0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))
        DrawCursorCoords(*gfx, *bmap, Gdiplus::Color::Red);
    else
        DrawCursorCoords(*gfx, *bmap, Gdiplus::Color::Green);

    delete gfx;
    delete bmap;
}

LRESULT APIENTRY WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        Paint(hdc);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
    }

    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, NULL);
        break;
    }

    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    }

    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    case WM_ERASEBKGND: return TRUE;

    default: return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);

    }

    return 0L;
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    char className[] = "_className";
    HWND hwnd = NULL;

    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_CROSS);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(0);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = className;

    if (RegisterClass(&wc))
    {
        hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
            WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_TOPMOST,
            className, NULL,
            WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,
            0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN),
            NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    }

    if (!hwnd) return FALSE;

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    SetTimer(hwnd, 1, 1, NULL);

    return TRUE;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Take a screenshot and store it to 'hbm'
    HWND hwndDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC hdcDesktop = GetDC(hwndDesktop);
    HDC hdcCapture = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcDesktop);
    hbm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcDesktop, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
    SelectObject(hdcCapture, hbm);
    BitBlt(hdcCapture, 0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN),
        hdcDesktop, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);

    // Start GDI+
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    MSG msg;

    InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    DeleteObject(hbm);
    ReleaseDC(hwndDesktop, hdcDesktop);
    DeleteDC(hdcDesktop);
    DeleteDC(hdcCapture);

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: It is the DrawImage() call that causes the flicker.  It overpaints the text previously drawn, then the DrawCursorCoords() puts it back.  Double-buffering is required to eliminate it, google "c++ gdi+ double buffering" for good hits.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: So... which C++ facility would you suggest to use, to implement a platform-agnostic GUI? If you cannot name one, what makes choosing the correct tool something you'd tag *"bad practice"*?

Comment: @IInspectable my first choices would be Qt, SFML & SDL. Most likely Qt. Hopefully that counts as "naming one".

Comment: @JesperJuhl: So instead of writing Windows specific code for a tool that targets Windows only, you suggest adding yet another dependency, and now making it Windows specific *and* library specific? Has overengineering been propagated to best practices recently? Besides, Qt is a toy, that cannot ever produce a GUI that's comparable to a native Windows desktop GUI. Its implementation is broken at the core, and cannot be fixed. You can easily identify a Qt application by using its keyboard interface, and wait for it to break. It will, inevitably. Always. Without an exception.

Comment: @IInspectable I can see we disagree on a few things. Not going to argue that here. I mentioned what *I*'d do, you said what *you*'d do. Let's leave it at that.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Incorrect. You flat-out claimed, that writing Windows-specific code for an application targeting Windows would somehow fall under *"bad practices"*. I'm glad you removed that comment.

Comment: My $.02 - Qt is way too heavyweight for me, unless you really, really need it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a buffer to paint. You can create a memory dc, or use `BeginBufferedPaint`:

```
#include <uxtheme.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "uxtheme.lib")
...

case WM_PAINT:
{
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    HDC memdc;
    auto hbuff = BeginBufferedPaint(hdc, &rc, BPBF_COMPATIBLEBITMAP, NULL, &memdc);
    Paint(memdc);
    EndBufferedPaint(hbuff, TRUE);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```

That should fix the flicker. I would suggest removing the timer and update the paint in mouse move instead:

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, NULL);
    break;
```

You may also want to explore `WS_EX_LAYERED` flag with `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`, this will create a transparent window which shows the desktop beneath it. It won't really need GDI+ for simple text drawing.

Also, Gdiplus has different constructors for most of its classes, that lets you avoid using `new`/`delete`. Example:

```
void DrawCursorCoords(Gdiplus::Graphics &graphics, Gdiplus::Bitmap&, Gdiplus::Color c)
{
    POINT cursorPos;
    GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);

    std::wstring x = std::to_wstring(cursorPos.x);
    std::wstring y = std::to_wstring(cursorPos.y);

    Gdiplus::Font font(L"Consolas", (Gdiplus::REAL)16);
    Gdiplus::SolidBrush brush(c);

    graphics.DrawString(x.c_str(), (int)x.length(), &font,
        Gdiplus::PointF((Gdiplus::REAL)cursorPos.x, (Gdiplus::REAL)cursorPos.y),
        &brush);

    graphics.DrawString(y.c_str(), (int)y.length(), &font,
        Gdiplus::PointF((Gdiplus::REAL)cursorPos.x, (Gdiplus::REAL)(cursorPos.y + 16)),
        &brush);
}

void Paint(HDC &hdc)
{
    Gdiplus::Graphics gfx(hdc);
    Gdiplus::Bitmap bmap(hbm, (HPALETTE)0);

    gfx.DrawImage(&bmap, 0, 0,
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));

    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))
        DrawCursorCoords(gfx, bmap, (Gdiplus::Color)Gdiplus::Color::Red);
    else
        DrawCursorCoords(gfx, bmap, (Gdiplus::Color)Gdiplus::Color::Green);
}
```

Or you can declare `Gdiplus::Bitmap *bmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(hbm, NULL);` this makes a copy of `hbm`, so you can make this more efficient by declaring `bmap` as global, and create/destroy it only once.

> ```
> ReleaseDC(hwndDesktop, hdcDesktop);
> DeleteDC(hdcDesktop); //<- not required
> ```

`DeleteDC(hdcDesktop)` is not required. `hdcDesktop` was from `GetDC`, it's cleaned up by `ReleaseDC`

> ```
> hbm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(...)
> SelectObject(hdcCapture, hbm);
> ...
> DeleteObject(hbm);
> ```

You should also restore the old bitmap as follows:

```
 hbm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(...)
 auto oldbitmap = SelectObject(hdcCapture, hbm);
 ...
 //cleanup
 SelectObject(hdcCapture, oldbitmap);
 DeleteObject(hbm);
```

Although if you don't restore the old bitmap, windows will try to fix the error anyway, so there won't be any problem most of the time.