# WIN32 how to cache drawing results to a bitmap?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Because there are hover and leave events of the mouse in the interface, if re drawing in each leave event leads to a large amount of resource occupation, how to draw and cache it in memory only when the program is started or the interface is notified of changes, and send `InvalidateRect()` to directly use `BitBlt` mapping instead of re drawing in the rest of the time?

```
int dystat = 0;
int anistat = 0;
    void CreatePanelDynamic(HWND h, HDC hdc, DRAWPANEL DrawFun, int Flag = 0)
    {

        //On hMemDC.
        if (PanelID == PrevPanelID)
        {
            //
            if (dystat == 0)
            {
                RECT rc;
                GetClientRect(h, &rc);

                BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, in_ghdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); //by bitmap
            }
            else
            {
                _CreatePanel(h, hdc, DrawFun); //directly
                dystat = 0;
            }
            anistat = 0;
        }
        if (PanelID != PrevPanelID) //animation
        {
            if (Flag == 0)
            {
                CreatePanelAnimation(h, hdc, DrawFun);
                dystat = 1;
            }
            if (Flag == 1)
            {
                _CreatePanel(h, hdc, DrawFun);
                dystat = 1;
            }
            PrevPanelID = PanelID;
            anistat = 0;
        }
    }
```

My program is already using MemDC.

Comment: You can redraw with the WM_PAINT event, or you can create a UI thread. The main thread uses PostThreadMessage to the UI thread, and the UI thread InvalidateRect() and draws with BitBlt.

To get redraw sizes in your code, you'd better to use `GetUpdateRect()` instead of `GetClientRect()`.

Comment: @jea How exactly does adding an additional thread help? Once all the required synchronization is set up, you'll wind up with sequential execution that just happens to take place on different threads. You also seem to ignore that this is real: [Why do messages posted by PostThreadMessage disappear?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090930-00/?p=16553)

Comment: My last question was blamed for creating threads,so I want to try draw the bitmap of the window now.

Comment: See this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/51330038/4603670 (the one with `BeginBufferedPaint`/`EndBufferedPaint`) it does the same thing as memory dc, a little easier. This example is for updating the whole window, but maybe you want to update one small region at the time.

Comment: But I want to directly use BitBlt to draw the cache map when the mouse leaves instead of calling it again_ CreatePanel (redraw the entire window),by the way,when mouse is hover in an area,Changes are drawn with GetDC,so there is no invalid region